# Declaring and indexing an integer array of qwords in assembly

Tags: arrays, assembly, x86-64, att

I have a question regarding how to initialize an array in assembly.  I tried:

```
.bss
#the array
unsigned:    .skip 10000
.data
#these are the values that I want to put in the array
par4:   .quad 500 
par5:   .quad 10
par6:   .quad 15
```

That's how I declared my string and the variables that I want to put it inside.
This is how I tried to put them into the array:

```
movq $0 , %r8

movq par4 , %rax
movq %rax , unsigned(%r8)
incq %r8

movq par5 , %rax
movq %rax , unsigned(%r8)
incq %r8

movq par6 , %rax
movq %rax , unsigned(%r8)
```

I tried printing the elements to check if everything is okay, and only the last one prints okay, the other two have some weird values.

Maybe this is not the way I should declare and work with it?

Comment: You're using `%r8` as a byte offset, and `incq %r8` only advances it by 1 byte, not 8.  You want either a scaled-index addressing mode or `add $8, %r8`.  Also, you could *statically* initialize your array by putting it in `.data` instead of bss, like the 3-element array starting at `par4`.  Or you could use `.equ` constants and use mov-immediate into memory.  Also there's no need to increment a pointer here, just store to `unsigned`, `unsigned+8`, and `unsigned+16`.

Comment: Also, `unsigned` is going to be an inconvenient choice of symbol name if you want to access the array from C.  `unsigned` is a keyword so you can't declare `extern uint64_t unsigned[1000/8]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, `unsigned` is the name of a type in C, so it's a poor choice for an array.  Let's call it `arr` instead.

You want to treat that block of space in the BSS as an array qword elements.  So each element is 8 bytes.  **So you need to store to `arr+0`, `arr+8`, and `arr+16`.**  (The total size of your array is 10000 bytes, which is 10000/8 qwords).

But you're using `%r8` as a byte offset, not a scaled-index.  That's generally a good thing, all else equal; indexed addressing modes are slower in some cases on some CPUs.  But the problem is you only increment it by `1` with `inc`, not with **`add $8, %r8`**.

So **you're actually storing to `arr+0`, `arr+1`, and `arr+2`, with 8-byte stores that overlap each other**, leaving just the least-significant byte of the last store.  x86 is little-endian so the resulting contents of memory is effectively this, followed by the rest of the unwritten bytes that stay zero.

```
# static array that matches what you actually stored
arr: .byte 500 & 0xFF, 10, 15, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...
```

You could of course just use `.qword` in the `.data` section to declare a static array with the contents you want.  But with only the first 3 element non-zero, putting it in the BSS makes sense for one that large, instead of a having the OS page in the zeros from disk.

---

If you're going to fully unroll instead of using a loop over your 3-element qword array starting at `par4`, you don't need to increment a register at all.  You also don't need the initializers to be in data memory, you can just use immediates because they all fit as 32-bit sign-extended.

```
  # these are assemble-time constants, not associated with a section
.equ par4, 500
.equ par5, 10
.equ par6, 15

.text  # already the default section but whatever

.globl _start
_start:
    movq    $par4, arr(%rip)            # use RIP-relative addressing when there's no register
    movq    $par5, arr+8(%rip)
    movq    $par6, arr+16(%rip)

    mov $60, %eax
    syscall               # Linux exit(0)

.bss
    arr:   .skip 10000
```

You can run that under GDB and examine memory to see what you get.  (Compile it with `gcc -nostdlib -static foo.s`).  In GDB, start the program with `starti` (to stop at the entry point), then single-step with `si`.  Use `x /4g  &arr` to dump the contents of memory at `arr` as an array of 4 qwords.

Or if you did want to use a register, might as well just loop a pointer instead of an index.

```
    lea     arr(%rip), %rdi           # or mov $arr, %edi in a non-PIE executable
    movq    $par4, (%rdi)
    add     $8, %rdi                  # advance the pointer 8 bytes = 1 element
    movq    $par5, (%rdi)
    add     $8, %rdi
    movq    $par6, (%rdi)
```

Or scaled-index:

```
## Scaled-index addressing
    movq    $par4, arr(%rip)
    mov     $1, %eax
    movq    $par5, arr(,%rax,8)       # [arr + rax*8]
    inc     %eax
    movq    $par6, arr(,%rax,8)
```

---

Fun trick: you could just do a byte store instead of a qword store to set the low byte, and leave the rest zero.  This would save code-size but if you did a qword load right away, you'd get a store-forwarding stall.  (~10 cycles extra latency for the store/reload to merge data from the cache with the store from the store buffer)

---

**Or if you *did* still want to copy 24 bytes from `par4` in `.rodata`**, you could use SSE.  x86-64 guarantees that SSE2 is available.

```
    movaps   par4(%rip), %xmm0
    movaps   %xmm0, arr(%rip)          # copy par4 and par5

    mov      par6(%rip), %rax          # aka par4+16
    mov      %rax, arr+16(%rip)

.section .rodata          # read-only data.
.p2align 4         # align by 2^4 = 16 for movaps
  par4:  .quad 500
  par5:  .quad 10
  par6:  .quad 15

.bss
.p2align 4        # align by 16 for movaps
  arr: .skip 10000
# or use .lcomm arr, 10000  without even switching to .bss
```

Or with SSE4.1, you can load+expand small constants so you don't need a whole qword for each small number that you're going to copy into the BSS array.

```
    movzxwq    initializers(%rip), %xmm0       # zero-extend 2 words into 2 qwords
    movaps     %xmm0, arr(%rip)
    movzwl     initializers+4(%rip), %eax      # zero-extending word load
    mov        %rax, arr+16(%rip)

.section .rodata
  initializers: .word 500, 10, 15
```

Comment: (I couldn't find a decent canonical Q&A for this to close it as a duplicate, so I decided to write one since the question is short, well-formatted, and doesn't have other distractions.  I know I've seen this bug many times, though.  Especially in Intel syntax where addressing have the same appearance as C array index which does scale the index.)