# Translate from nasm to gas assembly syntax

Tags: assembly, nasm, gnu-assembler, att, addressing-mode

translate this line:

```
mov [p2_label + ecx * 8], eax
```

what I understand it something like this:

```
movl %eax, (%ebx,%ecx,8)
```

But with label instead %ebx and it's not work for me.

Comment: Try `movl %eax, p2_label(,%ecx, 8)`.

Comment: Note quite a duplicate of [A couple of questions about \[base + index\*scale + disp\]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27936196)).  Also a much longer example that happens to include valid syntax for this: [Declaring and indexing an integer array of qwords in assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58402110).  Also you could look at C compiler output for array access: [How to remove "noise" from GCC/clang assembly output?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38552116)